# Missing plugin exception

Tags: flutter

I got an error for unhandled plugin exception for `google_fonts` and `shared_preferences`:

> Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found
> for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)
> Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found
> for method getApplicationSupportDirectory on channel
> plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)   MethodChannel.invokeMethod
> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:12)
> _localPath (package:google_fonts/src/file_io_desktop_and_mobile.dart:28:27)
> googleFontsTextStyle
> (package:google_fonts/src/google_fonts_base.dart:107:3)

Comment: I got an error for unhandled plugin exception for google_fonts and shared_preferences

Comment: stop your app, close vscode (or android studio) and reopen it and run pub get again, it should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks fro the reply but id didn't worked @DungNgo

Comment: can you also try running "flutter clean build" and re-build your app

Answer (score 2):

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

By adding above code solved the problem it was suggested on GitHub
[link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10912)

Answer (score 1):

I'm solved with change code from mainactivity.kt or mainactivity.java.

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
   override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: 
     FlutterEngine) {
     GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
   }
}
```

after that, flutter clean and run

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since Vishwesh Soni already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up once you have enough reputation.